# Checking availability of library book using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm learning python. And I'm trying to use it to automate the process of checking a library book's availability.

I tried executing it with bs4, request, and partition.

This is the link that I am trying to parse from: [http://catalogue.nlb.gov.sg/cgi-bin/spydus.exe/FULL/EXPNOS/BIBENQ/1592917/156302298,2][1]

I view its source code, and here's a snippet of it:

```html
<tr>
  <td valign="top"><a href="/cgi-bin/spydus.exe/ENQ/EXPNOS/GENENQ/1564461?LOCX=BIPL">**Bishan Public Library**</a>
    <br />
  </td>
  <td valign="top">
    <book-location data-title="The opposite of everyone" data-branch="BIPL" data-usagelevel="001" data-coursecode="" data-language="English" data-materialtype="BOOK" data-callnumber="JAC" data-itemcategory="" data-itemstatus="" data-lastreturndate="20160322"
    data-accession="B31189097E" data-defaultLoc="Adult Lending">Adult Lending</book-location>
  </td>
  <td valign="top"><a href="/cgi-bin/spydus.exe/ENQ/EXPNOS/BIBENQ/1564461?CGS=E*English">English</a>
    <br /><a href="/cgi-bin/spydus.exe/WBT/EXPNOS/BIBENQ/1564461?CNO=JAC&amp;CNO_TYPE=B">JAC</a>
    <br />
  </td>
  <td valign="top">**Available**
    <br />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td valign="top"><a href="/cgi-bin/spydus.exe/ENQ/EXPNOS/GENENQ/1564461?LOCX=BMPL">**Bukit Merah Public Library**</a>
    <br />
  </td>
  <td valign="top">
    <book-location data-title="The opposite of everyone" data-branch="BMPL" data-usagelevel="001" data-coursecode="" data-language="English" data-materialtype="BOOK" data-callnumber="JAC" data-itemcategory="" data-itemstatus="" data-lastreturndate="20160405"
    data-accession="B31189102C" data-defaultLoc="Adult Lending">Adult Lending</book-location>
  </td>
  <td valign="top"><a href="/cgi-bin/spydus.exe/ENQ/EXPNOS/BIBENQ/1564461?CGS=E*English">English</a>
    <br /><a href="/cgi-bin/spydus.exe/WBT/EXPNOS/BIBENQ/1564461?CNO=JAC&amp;CNO_TYPE=B">JAC</a>
    <br />
  </td>
  <td valign="top">**Available**
    <br />
  </td>
</tr>
```

The information that i am trying to parse is which library the book is available at.

Here's what I did:

```
import requests, bs4
>>> res = requests.get('http://catalogue.nlb.gov.sg/cgi-bin/spydus.exe/FULL/EXPNOS/BIBENQ/1592917/156302298,2')
>>> string = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)
```

Then I try to make *string* into a string:

```
>>> str(string)
```

And it printed the whole source code out and severely lagged my IDLE!

After it stopped lagging, I did this:

```
>>> keyword = '<a href="/cgi-bin/spydus.exe/ENQ/EXPNOS/GENENQ/1564461?LOCX='
>>> string.partition('keyword') Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    string.partition('keyword') TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I don't know why it caused an error, I did make the *string* into a string, right?

Also, I used that keyword because it is right before the "library branch" and right after "availability". So i thought even if it churns out a lot of other redundant code, I'll be able to see in the first line which library branch the book is available at.

I am sure the way I did it is not the most efficient way, and if you could point me to the right way, or show it to me, i will be extremely grateful!

I'm sorry this is a very long post, but i'm trying to be as detailed about my situation as possible. Thank you for bearing with me.

Answer (score 1):

No, you didn't make the `string` into a Python string, because you did not assign the result of `str(string)` to any variable, and it is therefore lost:

```
>>> type(string)
<class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>
>>> type(str(string))
<type 'str'>
>>> type(string)
<class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>
```

The variable `string` is unchanged. Try this:

```
>>> string = str(string)
>>> type(string)
<type 'str'>
```

Now you have a `str` string.

On a related note, why do you not use `BeautifulSoup` to extract the data from the HTML? That is what it's for, and what it's good at. Here is one way to do it:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get('http://catalogue.nlb.gov.sg/cgi-bin/spydus.exe/FULL/EXPNOS/BIBENQ/1592917/156302298,2').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

holdings = soup.find('table', class_='clsTab1').find_all('tr')
for holding in holdings:
    cells = holding.find_all('td')
    if cells:
        library = cells[0].text
        availability = cells[-1].text
        print('{}: {}'.format(library, availability))
```

**Output**

```
Ang Mo Kio Public Library: Available
Bedok Public Library: Available
Bishan Public Library: Available
Bukit Merah Public Library: Available
Central Public Library: Available
Geylang East Public Library: Available
Jurong Regional Library: Available
Jurong West Public Library: Available
library@orchard: Available
Marine Parade Public Library: Onloan - Due: 13 May 2016
Queenstown Public Library: Onloan - Due: 29 May 2016
Tampines Regional Library: Available
Toa Payoh Public Library: Available
Woodlands Regional Library: Available
```